# Opening a .pptx file in an office add-in

Tags: angular, typescript, powerpoint, office-addins

I'm working on a webapplication add-in that is running in the taskpane window of PowerPoint. The application gets .pptx files from a server and displays them using buttons so the user can select one. 
When the user selcts a file, it should open that file in a new window. I found out how to open files using typescript, but they won't open or download when I use this in the add-in.

This is the code I have tried:

```
async onClickTemplate() {
  window.location.href = 'file.pptx';
}
```

```
<button class="btn" (click)="onClickTemplate">Download</button>
```

They should work in a normal webapplication but when run in the PowerPoint taskpane, I only get an error in the taskpane. There is no error code, just a pop-up Error. Is there a workaround for this? Or is there other code I can try for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out I needed to use open and then add the correct path and got it working after that.

```
async onClickTemplate() {
    window.open('file.pptx')
  }
```

Comment: If you solved it, please provide a bit of code for people in the future